# Is it possible to pass a collection of entities to IN and NOT IN clauses?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

According to Spring Data JPA documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) it is possible to pass a collection of entities to the `IN` and `NOT IN` clauses.

[image]

`Age` here is an entity. However, in practice, it seems like this is not possible.

Clone the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/honest-niceman/collection-of-entities-in-not-in-clauses), or just copy and paste the entities below to reproduce. Here is an example:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "specialties")
public class Specialty {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "vets")
public class Vet {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "vet_specialties",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "vet_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "specialty_id")
    )
    private Set<Specialty> specialties;

    public void addSpecialty(Specialty specialty) {
        this.specialties.add(specialty);
    }
}
import com.example.demo.entity.Specialty;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface SpecialtyRepository extends JpaRepository<Specialty, Long> {
}
```

The key moment:

```
import com.example.demo.entity.Specialty;
import com.example.demo.entity.Vet;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public interface VetRepository extends JpaRepository<Vet, Long> {

    @Query("select v from Vet v where v.specialties in ?1")
    List<Vet> findBySpecialtiesIn(Collection<Specialty> specialties);

}
```

As you can see, I am trying to fetch vets by specialties.

And here is the test for it:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final SpecialtyRepository specialtyRepository;
    private final VetRepository vetRepository;

    public DemoApplication(SpecialtyRepository specialtyRepository,
                           VetRepository vetRepository) {
        this.specialtyRepository = specialtyRepository;
        this.vetRepository = vetRepository;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        Set<Specialty> specialties = new HashSet<>();
        specialties.add(new Specialty());
        specialties.add(new Specialty());
        specialties.add(new Specialty());
        specialties.add(new Specialty());

        specialtyRepository.saveAll(specialties);

        Vet vet = new Vet();

        specialties.forEach(vet::addSpecialty);

        vetRepository.save(vet);

        vetRepository.findBySpecialtiesIn(specialties);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:770) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:751) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:23) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.NotYetImplementedFor6Exception: org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.internal.PluralValuedSimplePathInterpretation
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.internal.PluralValuedSimplePathInterpretation.accept(PluralValuedSimplePathInterpretation.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitInListPredicate(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:5189) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.predicate.InListPredicate.accept(InListPredicate.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitWhereClause(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:1650) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitQuerySpec(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:1596) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLSqlAstTranslator.visitQuerySpec(PostgreSQLSqlAstTranslator.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.select.QuerySpec.accept(QuerySpec.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitSelectStatement(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:834) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.translateSelect(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:707) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.translate(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.buildCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:407) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:571) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.list(QuerySqmImpl.java:1073) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:401) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy101.getResultList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:127) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:148) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy97.findBySpecialtiesIn(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.run(DemoApplication.java:42) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

So, my question is simple. Is it just misleading typo in the documentation or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You dont understood right, how to use `IN` or `NOT IN` you can not use it to ManyToMany relation: to use `IN` or `NOT IN` you should have something like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**answer to you questions is: you doing something wrong.**

Comment: You are not right. I just found out what is the reason. The reason is that JQPL doesn't support IN and NOT IN clauses for entities. So, I can just use the derived method from Spring Data JPA and everything will work as I want:
```
//@Query("select v from Vet v where v.specialties in ?1")
List<Vet> findBySpecialtiesIn(Collection<Specialty> specialties);
```
And the answer for my question is: JQPL doesn't support IN and NOT IN clauses for the collection of entities. Use derived method instead.

But anyway, thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Also, this is the valid JQPL query:

@Query("SELECT DISTINCT v FROM Vet v LEFT JOIN v.specialties s WHERE s IN :specialties")
 List<Vet> findBySpecialtiesIn(Collection<Specialty> specialties);

Comment: good point, i forgot about join in collections with `IN`, the important point, you solve your problem )